# Setting cell in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I am attempting to set an `imageView` in a `cell` in a `UICollectionview`. No images ever appear. I am also tried to set a label but have had no luck

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    photoCollectionViewCell *photoCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURLArray[indexPath.row]];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    //photoCell.photoImageView.image = tmpImage;
    photoCell.photoLabel.text = @"l";

    return photoCell;
}
```

One thing I did notice is that "photoCell" always returns null.

I am registering my collectionview like this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[photoCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
```

My cell interface header file is:

```
@interface photoCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoImageView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *photoLabel;

@end
```

Comment: have you set delegates of collectionview in storyboard or view controller?

Answer (score 1):

My **first guess** would be to return an instance of photoCollectionViewCell instead of the default UICollectionViewCell:

```
- (photoCollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}
```

**Second guess**:

Where do you set your "reuseIdentifier" variable and what value is assigned to it? You can set a reuseIdentifier as follows:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";
```

and then set it to your:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[photoCollectionViewCell class] CellIdentifier];
```

and:

```
photoCollectionViewCell *photoCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and register your ReuseIdentifier on your storyboard custom cell:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that was a bug. Unfortunately, it did not fix my problem :(

Comment: I set  reuseIdentifier  at the top of my @implementation for the view controller.

Comment: @kinezu Did you set the reuseIdentifier in your storyboard, on the cell?

Comment: I think I have that set up right. Here is what I have in the storyboard: http://screencast.com/t/nHuP4ZJl  and here is what I have in my view implimentation: static NSString * const reuseIdentifier = @"photoCell";